# What writer meant by using "has" in the given sentences?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I encountered with this form of causative. At first, it was not that peculiar. The part that underlined with an **orange line**,i thought, simply meant that Plato made Socrates to articulate the reproach. However, in the part where i lined it with **green** it wasn't the case. It seems as if plato made socrates recount how he had been enthusiastic about physics, but had come to be disillusioned by it even though it was made clear by the writer that it was Plato who talked about his disappointment. Could you tell me what the writer actually meant by using has in the given sentences?.[image: screenshot of the mentioned sentences]

Comment: Apparently _Phaedo_ takes the form of a (fictional) conversation involving Socrates shortly before his execution. So you are correct that Plato represents Socrates as expressing those ideas. "Plato's Socrates recounts..." means that Socrates, as represented by Plato, tells this story of his disillusionment.  But presumably Plato wrote the dialogue to express his own ideas.

Comment: Are you interpreting the meaning to be that Plato told Socrates to act in various ways, such as to *articulate a reproach*? As @KateBunting notes, Plato is explaining what Socrates had done during past events. The events may not be fictional, but the author of the passage is emphasizing that our understanding of Socrates's actions are known to us indirectly  through Plato, who may not be a reliable witness. Thus, the meaning is *In Plato's telling of the early events, Socrates articulated a reproach...*

Comment: Thanks to both of you i got the clarification that i needed. Yes, i construed  the first sentence as Plato telling Socrates to behave in a given manner without considering the fact that it was Plato who wrote the book and representing Socrates with his point of view

Comment: This usage can be confusing, and is actually slightly informal. The reason why scholars like to use it to describe someone telling a narrative is to emphasize that the version of the narrative depends on the person telling it. The use of *to have* in this sense is the same as in, "I have my windows closed", instead of "my windows are closed". The first form emphasizes that I made the decision. If someone else decided, then the windows might be open.